# Pass data frame by row to a function as a list

Tags: r, list, function, dplyr

I'm trying to run a function over each row of a data frame using `rowwise()` and `dplyr` by passing each row as a list to the function and then using column names to access the variables.

The code below shows what I'm trying to do. The code passes the whole data frame to the function, it doesn't step through each row. Any suggestions please?

```
    #initial dataframe
df <-  data.frame(X=c(10,22,43,47,15), Y=c(2,3,4,2,2))

## cumbersome version - pass each variable
dfResult <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Z=FnAdd(X,Y)) %>% 
  mutate(K=FnMult(X,Y,Z))

FnAdd <- function(X,Y){
  R <- c()  
  for(i in 1:4){
    R[i]=X+i*Y
  }
  return (list(R))
}

FnMult <- function(X,Y,Z){
  R <- c()  
  for(i in 1:4){
    R[i]=X+i*Y*2*Z[i]
  }
  return (list(R))
}


##concise version - just pass a list of each row
#code runs but is incorrect - it always uses the first row
dfResultX <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Z=FnAddX(as.list(dfResult))) %>% 
  mutate(K=FnMultX(as.list(dfResult)))

#function should receive a list of one row
#actually receives list of whole data frame
FnAddX <- function(Vars){
  R <- c()  
  for(i in 1:4){
    R[i]=Vars$X+i*Vars$Y
  }
  return (list(R))
}

#ditto
debug(FnMultX)
FnMultX <- function(Vars){
  R <- c()  
  for(i in 1:4){
    V1 <- Vars$X
    V2 <- Vars$Y
    #next line of code is wrong and crashes function
    V3 <- Vars$Z[1][i]
    R[i]=Vars$X+i*Vars$Y*2*Vars$Z[i]
  }
  return (list(R))
}

#loop option
#not ideal but could work if dplyr won't
Result <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  RowList <- as.list(df[i,])
  NewVec <- FnAddX(RowList)
  Result <- append(Result,NewVec)
}
#bind result to original data frame
#code not working - not sure how to do this
dfResultX <- df %>% 
    as.data.frame(Result)
```

Comment: Is `FnAdd` what you'd actually like to do for each row? Or is that a simple example?

Comment: No it's just a simple example. The actual app has about 15 variables and I think using a list (like a class in C#) is more concise. Subsequent functions also use previous results.

Comment: @Zeus Can you show what you expect as output after each function? Use `df <- data.frame(X=c(10,22), Y=c(2,3)` as the example

Comment: @CPak - good idea, I've re-written the code in the question and added a loop option which should work but is not ideal